# handling multipart form data MVC6 webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

With asp.net webapi 2, to check if a request contains multipart/formdata was as simple as calling the Request.Content.IsMimeMultipart() method. This method doesn't seem to exist. As a matter of fact, the entire Mimemultipart extension methods are absent.

What is the work around or the new way to handle this in MVC 6

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but this shows file uploads in the MVC6 tests: [FileUploadController.cs](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/6.0.0-beta8/test/WebSites/ModelBindingWebSite/Controllers/FileUploadController.cs)

Comment: @JeffOgata. Thanks. Will check it out and get back to you

Comment: Any solution yet? I think, I have the similar problem here http://stackoverflow.com/q/40629947/1306394. Please let me know if you've found any workaround.