# .NET 6 Minimal API and multipart/form-data

Tags: rest, asp.net-core, multipartform-data, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

Using the .NET 6 Minimal API, I'm trying to handle `multipart/form-data` in the POST method. However, with the following code:

```cs
app.MapPost("/tickets", async (IFreshdeskApiService s, [FromForm] CreateTicketDto dto) => await s.Add(dto))
   .Accepts<CreateTicketDto>("multipart/form-data");
```

I'm receiving 400 Bad Request with body:

```json
{
    "error": "Expected a supported JSON media type but got \"multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------391539519671819893009831\"."
}
```

I switched to the non-minimal API (i.e. using `app.MapControllers()`), but is there any way to handle this in minimal API?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Please see the Explicit Parameter Binding section of [Minimal APIs overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-6.0#explicit-parameter-binding):

> Binding from form values is **not** supported in .NET 6.

So, unfortunately, using `[FromForm]` attribute and binding from forms is not supported in .NET 6 in minimal APIs.

---

**Custom Model Binding Workaround**

There is a workaround using custom model binding.  This was inspired by Ben Foster's post [Custom Model Binding in ASP.NET 6.0 Minimal APIs](https://benfoster.io/blog/minimal-apis-custom-model-binding-aspnet-6/).  The basic idea is to add a `BindAsync` method to your type/class with the following signature:

```cs
public static ValueTask<TModel?> BindAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ParameterInfo parameter)
```

For your example I created a simple `record` with 3 properties `Id`, `Name` and `Status`.  Then you use `HttpContext.Request.Form` collection to get the required values from the `Request`:

```cs
public record CreateTicketDto(int Id, string Name, string Status)
{
    public static ValueTask<CreateTicketDto?> BindAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        // parse any values required from the Request
        int.TryParse(httpContext.Request.Form["Id"], out var id);

        // return the CreateTicketDto
        return ValueTask.FromResult<CreateTicketDto?>(
            new CreateTicketDto(
                id,
                httpContext.Request.Form["Name"],
                httpContext.Request.Form["Status"]
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Now you can send data to the API using FormData without receiving an error.

[image: image showing success in postman]

Personally, I would remove the `[FromForm]` attribute from the endpoint, however, in my testing it works with or without it.  The above technique will work with `class` types too, not just `record`s.

---

**Simpler alternative**

A simpler implementation is to pass `HttpContext` into the action and read all values from the `ctx.Request.Form` collection. In this case your action might look something like the following:

```cs
app.MapPost("/tickets", (HttpContext ctx, IFreshdeskApiService s) =>
{
    // read value from Form collection
    int.TryParse(ctx.Request.Form["Id"], out var id);
    var name = ctx.Request.Form["Name"];
    var status = ctx.Request.Form["Status"];

    var dto = new CreateTicketDto(id, name, status);
 
    s.Add(dto);
    return Results.Accepted(value: dto);
});
```

Comment: Great, thank you for providing an alternative. It doesn't seem to be Minimal anymore, especially for handling multiple fields, but glad it works.

Comment: There is an open github issue: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39430 so support for `[FromForm]` might be added back in .net 7

Comment: This is now supported in .NET 8 Preview 6 onwards

Comment: @JaliyaUdagedara for me it seems that complex object are still not supported into -NET8 with FromForm in Minimal API. Could you show an example working in .NET8?

Comment: @LuigiSaggese, can you check this:
https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2023/10/net-8-rc-2-iformfile-support-in.html