# MinimalAPI - Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromService] or [FromBody] attribute?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I created an asp.net core empty project and whenever I am trying to run my application it gives me the error shown below. I cannot even hit the end point as soon I hit play it gives the error.

System.InvalidOperationException
HResult=0x80131509
Message=Body was inferred but the method does not allow inferred body parameters.
Below is the list of parameters that we found:

```
Parameter           | Source                        
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ur                  | Service (Attribute)
userLogin           | Body (Inferred)


Did you mean to register the "Body (Inferred)" parameter(s) as a Service or apply the [FromService] or [FromBody] attribute?
```

No idea why I am getting this error. I then tried adding `[FromService]` and it says the same error as well. I read this [article](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-dotnet-6-part-7-analyzers-for-minimal-apis/#-bind-isn-t-valid-on-minimal-apis) for the same issue but it says do not add `[Bind]` which I was not in the first place and to instead use `[FromService]` but I still get the same error. Is there something wrong I am doing?

`Program.cs`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(x =>
    x.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGet("/", () => "Hello World!");

app.MapGet("/userLogin", (IUserRepository ur, UserLogin userLogin) =>
{
    return ur.Get(userLogin);
});

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger(x => x.SerializeAsV2 = true);
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.Run();
```

`UserLogin`:

```
 [Keyless]
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

`UserRepository`:

```
public User Get(UserLogin userLogin)
        {   // get the username and password make sure what was entered matches in the DB then return the user
            var username =_dbContext.Users.Find(userLogin.Username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

            return username;
        }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The exception message is telling you the problem:

> Body was inferred but the method does not allow inferred body
> parameters

The binder has inferred the `UserLogin` parameter as a parameter from the body, but inferred body parameters are not allowed.

The simplest way to get this working is to add `[FromBody]` attribute to the `UserLogin` parameter, however, in that case you should really change the method to POST since GET requests don't have a body.

```
app.MapPost("/userLogin", (IUserRepository ur, [FromBody]UserLogin userLogin) => {...}
```

Unfortunately, it's not possible to bind complex objects from query string values using `[FromQuery]` attribute in minimal APIs so your best option IMO is to use `[FromBody]` and `MapPost`.

If you need to use `MapGet` there is a work-around by adding a static `BindAsync` method to your `UserLogin` class - more details can be found in [this blog post](https://benfoster.io/blog/minimal-apis-custom-model-binding-aspnet-6/). Another alternative is to pass `HttpContext` to the action and take the values from the context - see [this similar answer for binding [FromForm]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71048827/9665021) - you'd use `ctx.Request.Query["username"]` to get the username from the HttpContext.

Comment: Thank you, I realized after reading your explanation  I should have to change it to a POST method instead of a GET.

Answer (score 21):

In my case I forgot to add the below to my program.cs file above my  app.Run();

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
```

Comment: Good catch, all too easily overlooked. Helped save hours of trawling online. Thanks!

Comment: This worked also for me, however, still did not get why the MapGet failed with the exception System.InvalidOperationException when running ?

Comment: Maybe it is because of the dependency missing injection for that interface class?

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to use `MapGet`, you'll need to add a `BindAsync` method to the UserLogin class

```
public class UserLogin
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public static ValueTask<UserLogin> BindAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        var result = new UserLogin
        {
            Username = context.Request.Query[nameof(Username)],
            Password = context.Request.Query[nameof(Password)],
        };

        return ValueTask.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Been long but from what I've checked.NET 6 wont let You specify model parameters without FromBody attribute but only for verbs that shouldnt base on model anyway, like DELETE or GET. You can in fact write POST/PUT requests without specyfing bind attributes thou.

Wont work:

```
app.MapDelete("/", (SomeModel model) => ...)
app.MapGet("/", (SomeModel model) => ...)
```

Will work:

```
app.MapPost("/", (SomeModel model) => ...)
app.MapPut("/", (SomeModel model) => ...)
```