# Accept x-www-form-urlencoded in Minimal API NET 6

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, minimal-apis

I'm trying to send a "Content-Type" header: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
to a minimal api and I get the following error:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.BadHttpRequestException: Expected a
> supported JSON media type but got "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

Here's the endpoint:

```
app.MapPost("/api/formulario/imovel-web/cadastrar",
            async (LeadRequest request, ILeadService service, ILogService logService, ICorretorMrvRepository corretorMrvRepository) =>
{
    request.Origem = "imovelweb";

    try
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.Token))
        {
            logService.Error("leads-api", "imovel-web: Acesso não autorizado (Token não encontrado).", Environment.StackTrace, request: request.Serialize());

            return Result.ResponseFailed("Acesso não autorizado (Token não encontrado).");
        }
        else
        {
            var idParceiro = await corretorMrvRepository.ObterIdParceiro("imovelweb");
            var origem = string.Empty;

            if (idParceiro != Guid.Empty)
            {

                var jwt = request.Token;
                var handler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                var data = handler.ReadJwtToken(request.Token);

                var autorizado = data.Claims.Any(x => x.Type.Equals("origin") && x.Value.Equals("imovelweb")) &&
                                 data.Claims.Any(x => x.Type.Equals("key") && x.Value.Equals(idParceiro.ToString()));

                if (!autorizado)
                {
                    logService.Error("leads-api", "imovel-web: Acesso não autorizado.", Environment.StackTrace, request: request.Serialize());

                    return Result.ResponseFailed("Acesso não autorizado (Dados do token não encontrados).");
                }

                request.Origem = await corretorMrvRepository.ValidaParceiroLead(idParceiro);
            }
            else
            {
                logService.Error("leads-api", "imovel-web: Acesso não autorizado (Id do parceiro não encontrado).", Environment.StackTrace, request: request.Serialize());

                return Result.ResponseFailed("Acesso não autorizado (Id do parceiro não encontrado).");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.txtDdd) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(request.txtTelefone))
                request.txtTelefone = $"{request.txtDdd}{request.txtTelefone}".FormatPhone(false);

            var responseResult = await service.Cadastrar(request);

            return Result.Response<ResponseResult>(responseResult, responseResult.Success);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        logService.Error("leads-api", new ExceptionForLog(e.Message, e));
        return Result.ResponseFailed(e.Message);
    }
})
.Accepts<LeadRequest>("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
.Produces<ResponseResult>()
.ProducesValidationProblem()
.WithTags("Imóvel Web")
.WithName("CadastrarImovelWeb");
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is the same problem as [.NET 6 Minimal API and multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047077/net-6-minimal-api-and-multipart-form-data).  The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71048827/9665021) explains it's not currently possible to bind form values in minimal APIs. However, there are a couple of work-arounds which are detailed in the answer:

1. Custom Model Binding via `BindAsync`
2. Map the values straight from `HttpContext`

---

**Utilizing MVC Core model binding**

However, there is another method where we can leverage some of the model-binding mechanisms that already exist in MVC, in your minimal API.  The below is inspired by Abuhakmeh's page [Using ASP.NET Core MVC Value Providers With Minimal APIs](https://khalidabuhakmeh.com/using-aspnet-core-mvc-value-providers-with-minimal-apis).

First, add a `BindAsync` method to your model (`LeadRequest`) which generates an instance from the request context:

```
public class LeadRequest
{
    // class properties
    ...

    public static async ValueTask<LeadRequest?> BindAsync(HttpContext httpContext, ParameterInfo parameter)
    {
        return await httpContext.BindFromForm<LeadRequest>();
    }
}
```

where I've assumed `LeadRequest` is a class but this will work with records too.

Now, you need to add an extension method for `BindFromForm<T>()`. This utilizes model-binding available in Asp.Net MVC Core.

```
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace YourProjectNamespace;

public static class BindingExtensions
{
    public static async Task<T?> BindFromForm<T>(this HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var serviceProvider = httpContext.RequestServices;
        var factory = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IModelBinderFactory>();
        var metadataProvider = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IModelMetadataProvider>();

        var metadata = metadataProvider.GetMetadataForType(typeof(T));
        var modelBinder = factory.CreateBinder(new() {
            Metadata = metadata
        });

        var context = new DefaultModelBindingContext
        {
            ModelMetadata = metadata,
            ModelName = string.Empty,
            ValueProvider = new FormValueProvider(
                BindingSource.Form,
                httpContext.Request.Form,
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            ),
            ActionContext = new ActionContext(
                httpContext, 
                new RouteData(), 
                new ActionDescriptor()),
            ModelState = new ModelStateDictionary()
        };
        await modelBinder.BindModelAsync(context);
        return (T?) context.Result.Model;
    }
}
```

Finally, you need to register MVC Core with your application services:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddMvcCore();

...

app.MapPost("/api/formulario/imovel-web/cadastrar",
    async (LeadRequest request, ILeadService service, ILogService logService, ICorretorMrvRepository corretorMrvRepository) =>
{
    ...
}
```

This will bind the request data to your model.  Note: there's no need to use `Accepts<LeadRequest>("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")` when using this method.