# FromBody attribute not working for app.MapPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, minimal-apis

I have a form posting to endpoint /api/vendors/add.  when I submit the form it gives me the error,

This page isn’t working
If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 415

when I remove the param it works just fine.  What am I doing wrong/missing.  Everything I gooogled on param binding in min apis shows this as being a viable option.

```
<form method="post" action="/api/vendors/add">
    <input type="text" name="vendor_name" placeholder="Vendor Name" size="45"/><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="vendor_id" placeholder="Vendor#" size="45"/><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="alpha_name" placeholder="Alpha" size="45" /><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="default_account" placeholder="Default Account"/><br /><br />
    <input type="text" name="default_department" placeholder="Default Department" size="45"/><br /><br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
app.MapPost("/api/vendors/add", ([FromBody] string jsonString) => {
    return "/api/vendors/add/result";
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET 6 Minimal API and multipart/form-data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71047077/net-6-minimal-api-and-multipart-form-data)

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [parameter binding section of the Minimal APIs docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#parameter-binding)  (except for file uploads via `IFormFile`/`IFormFileCollection` since .NET 7)
:

> Binding from **form** values is not natively supported in .NET.

You can try using custom binding via [`BindAsync` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/minimal-apis?view=aspnetcore-7.0#bindasync) (do not forget to add `.Accepts("multipart/form-data")` call) or manually process the form data:

```cs
app.MapPost("/form", (HttpContext todo, CancellationToken token) => todo.Request.Form.Keys)
    .Accepts<Todo>("multipart/form-data")
    .Produces(200);
```

But I would argue you should switch to other variants provided by the framework like controllers or Razor pages.

See also:

- [Exploring the model-binding logic of minimal APIs](https://andrewlock.net/behind-the-scenes-of-minimal-apis-3-exploring-the-model-binding-logic-of-minimal-apis/#1-binding-from-parameters)
- [Support Form binding for Minimal endpoints](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39430) github issue.